# Angular-ui bootstrap modal opens too slowly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an Angular-ui Bootstrap modal in my Angular app:

```
<div class="modal-header">  
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <textarea ng-model="text" id="imageCaption" maxlength="1000" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#imageCaption").myFunc();
    });
</script>
```

---

I want the script function to run after the Bootstrap modal is opened. Right now, when I click to open the modal, it opens only after a while because it runs the function first. I want to open the modal faster.

Comment: can u make a fiddlle?

Answer (score 2):

Following the Angular way, you would call a function after the modal opens by using the `opened` method on the object returned by the `open` method, such as `<button ng-click="open()">open</button>`:

```
$myModal.opened.then(function(){
  // your function
});
```

UI Bootstrap's $modal service's `open` method returns a modal instance, which has the `opened` property, a promise that is resolved after the modal dialog finishes opening.